# How to trim the values passing the in clause of the select query

Tags: sql-server-2012, select

Below is simple sql query to select records using in condition.

```
--like this I have 6000 usernames
select * from tblUsers where Username in ('abc  ','xyz  ',' pqr  ',' mnop  ' );
```

I know there are `LTrim` & `Rtrim` in sql to remove the leading trailing spaces form left & right respectively.

I want to remove the spaces from left & right in all the usernames that I am supplying to the select query.

**Note**:-

- I want to trim the values that I am passing in the `in` clause.(*I don't want to pass LTrim & RTrim to each value passed*).
- There are no trailing space in the records but  value that I am passing in the clause is copied from excel & then pasted in Visual Studio. Then using ALT key I put '(single quote) at the left & right sides of the string. Due to this some strings has spaces in the right side trailing.

> How to use the `trim` function in the select query?

I am using MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Are there any spaces in the usernames?

Comment: @hot2use, While inserting the records we have used `C# trim()`, so I don't think so there would be any space

Comment: Could there be valid usernames containing spaces like: 'this user' or 'another user'? Next point: C# trim function removes leading and trailing spaces, so why would you have to remove the spaces again? Your output/string should already be something like 'user name','username1','username2','abc','xyz',...

Comment: Why don't you want to use both  `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` on the values? That would effectively result in a `TRIM`

Comment: @TomV, You think for 6000 users I will write these functions. Doesn't it seems wiered?

Comment: Right hand trailing spaces don't make any difference to `in` comparisons. Why can't you use the [concatenate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8F8AE884-2CA8-4F7A-B093-75D702BEA31D) function to append the quotes and comma in Excel before copying them. Then you won't be introducing any in the first place.

Comment: Would a single `TRIM` around each value be that much cleaner? Or maybe I misunderstand your goal

Comment: @MartinSmith, are you sure that Right hand trailing space doesn't make any difference ??

Comment: Yes https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/316626

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly you are pasting from Excel into an `IN` clause in an adhoc query as below.

[image]

The trailing spaces don't matter. It will still match the string `foo` without any trailing spaces.

But you need to ensure that there are no leading spaces.

As the source of the data is Excel why not just do it all there?

You can use formula

```
= CONCATENATE("'",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'","''")),"',")
```

[image]

Then copy the result (from column B in the screenshot above) and just need to trim off the extra comma from the final entry.

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this:

```
select * from tblUsers where LTRIM(RTRIM(Username)) in (ltrim(rtrim('abc')),ltrim(rtrim('xyz')),ltrim(rtrim('pqr')),ltrim(rtrim('mnop')));
```

However, if you have permission to update the database. Please remove all the spaces in your `Username` field. It is really not good to do the query like this.

Comment: I tried your query. There is a user with username useradmin when I pass this query `select * from tblUsers where LTRIM(RTRIM(Username)) in ('abc','  useradmin  ');` It doesn't return the records while if rewrite the query as `select * from tblUsers where Username in ('abc',' useradmin');` It returns one record. (Note, no space in the second query)

Comment: The value in the list of query should not include spaces in beginning and end. You should only use 'useradmin'

Comment: The function will left and right trim spaces of value in DB. So the value to compare must not contains the spaces. I think it's very obvious.

Comment: Do you want to search the column `tblUsers` with whitespaces? I don't understand when you would want to do that!!!

Comment: I want to trim the values that I am passing in the `in` clause that I am passing in the select query

Comment: @Darshan_Viswanath_BI

Comment: @Kgn-web: so just do it, select * from tblUsers where LTRIM(RTRIM(Username)) in (LTRIM(RTRIM(' abc ')), LTRIM(RTRIM(' xyz '))...); I really don't understand why you need to do it. Are you building dynamic SQL.

Comment: You meant to say that I need to append these functions in each value that I am passing??

Comment: @Kgn-web It is bad practice to have spaces at the beginning and ending of strings. Whatever is causing this in your program must be fixed before data is inserted into your database.

Comment: @Kgn-web, yes it is, you need to do it

Comment: @KwekuReginaldWade, Who told you that I am inserting, its a select query

Comment: @Kgn-web Then use RTRIM and LTRIM against the select query and use the result in the where clause you have above

Comment: @Kgn-web if there are user names in your database that have leading and trailing spaces, then they need to be cleaned.

Comment: @KwekuReginaldWade, There are no trailing space in the records but t this is the list of users , copied from excel & I need to check if there is any matching username. But when I copied from excel some usernames had spaces in the trailing right side

Comment: @Kgn-web, I understand. Unfortunately there is no way to trim an item in the IN Clause list. Have you considered using the TRIM() function in Excel, then taking that column as your list?

Comment: Every string doesn't have same length. So what I did I just copied from excel & then pasted in Visual Studio. Then using ALT key I put `'`(single quote) at the left & right sides of the string. Due to this some strings has spaces in the right trailing side

Answer (score 1):

One way to tackle your problem and still be able to benefit from an index on username is to use a persisted computed column:

**Setup**

```
-- drop table dbo.tblUsers
create table dbo.tblUsers
(
    UserId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) CONSTRAINT PK_UserTest PRIMARY KEY,
    Username NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    UsernameTrimmed AS LTRIM(RTRIM(Username)) PERSISTED
)
GO

-- other columns may be included here with INCLUDE (col1, col2)
CREATE INDEX IDX_UserTest ON dbo.tblUsers (UsernameTrimmed)
GO

insert into dbo.tblUsers (Username) VALUES ('abc  '),('xyz  '),(' pqr  '), (' mnop  '), ('abc'), (' useradmin '), ('etc'), (' other user ')
GO 

-- some mock data to obtain a large number of records
insert into dbo.tblUsers (Username) 
select top 20000 SUBSTRING(text, 1, 64) from sys.messages 
GO
```

**Test**

```
-- this will use the index (index seek)
select * from tblUsers where UsernameTrimmed in (LTRIM(RTRIM('abc')), LTRIM(RTRIM(' useradmin ')));
```

This allows for faster retrievals at the expense of extra space.

In order to get rid of query construction (and the ugliness of many `LTRIM`s and `RTRIM`s), you can push searched users in a table that looks like `tblUsers`.

```
create table dbo.searchedUsers
(
    Username NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    UsernameTrimmed AS LTRIM(RTRIM(Username)) PERSISTED
)
GO
```

Push raw values into `dbo.searchedUsers.Username` column and the query should look like this:

```
select U.* 
from tblUsers AS U 
   join dbo.searchedUsers AS S ON S.UsernameTrimmed = U.UsernameTrimmed
```

**The big picture**

It is way better to properly trim your data in the service layer of your application (C#) so that future clients of your table may rely on decent information. So, trimming should be performed both when inserting information into `tblUsers` and when searching for users (IN values)

Comment: High worth post. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tblUsers
where RTRIM(LTRIM(Username)) in ('abc','xyz','pqr','mnop');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Answer: SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Username)) in ('abc','xyz','pqr','mnop');
```

However, please note that if you have `functions` in your `WHERE` clause it defeats the purpose of having an `indexes` on that column and will use a 
`scan` than a `seek`.

I would propose you clean your data before inserting into `tblUsers`

Comment: I tried your query. There is a user with username useradmin when I pass this query `select * from tblUsers where LTRIM(RTRIM(Username)) in ('abc','  useradmin  ');` It doesn't return the records while if rewrite the query as `select * from tblUsers where Username in ('abc',' useradmin');` It returns one record. (Note, no space in the second query)

Comment: Isn't that the whole purpose of LTRIM and RTRIM? You remove white spaces in your column? If you want `select * from tblUsers where LTRIM(RTRIM(Username)) in ('abc',' useradmin ');` this to work then remove `trims`

Comment: Ah!!! what you should do is: trim your usernames before you supply it in the query.. Where are you generating values to search for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

Just replace the table2 with you table name form where you are getting the username

```
  select * from tblUsers where Username in ((select distinct 
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(t1.Username))
         from table2 t1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,'') UserName
from table2 t) );
```

Comment: What you are trying??Please elaborate

Comment: I have removed the unwanted space from user name when we are selecting that value from db and added the , in between them so that they can work in " In "clause .

Comment: Column or parameters??

Comment: parameters which we are selecting from db

Comment: The source of usernames is not any table/db but a manual copy-pasted string.

Comment: So you can remove that unwanted space by code and pass the proper value in sql  like we can use .trim() in C# for removing unwanted space

Comment: Isn't it an overhead :)

Comment: Not in query boss

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in two step:
1) populate a temp table with all your strings with blanks
2) do a select with a subselect

```
create table a (a char(1))

insert into a values('a')
insert into a values('b')
insert into a values('c')
insert into a values('d')

create table #b (atmp char(5))

insert into #b values ('a  ')
insert into #b values (' b')
insert into #b values (' c  ')

select * from a where a in (select ltrim(rtrim(atmp)) from #b)
```